# Tokyo tyrant database size limit

Tags: key-value-store, tokyo-cabinet, tokyo-tyrant

I have a database with 65GB and it looks like it is not accepting new entries.

Is there any limit for tokyo tyrant database size?

Comment: A similar problem was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077952/tokyo-cabinet-hash-table-breaks-when-reaching-65-gb